# "configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check"

Tags: compiling, c++, configure

```
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~$ cd Desktop
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop$ cd libgraph-1.0.2
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$ 
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$ 
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$ sudo make
[sudo] password for apcoer: 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$
```

Can anyone solve this error urgently...?

Answer (score 4):

You should try

```
sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential
```

Then

```
./configure && make
```

The problem is you don't have compiler so `configure` script does not generate the `Makefile` properly.

Comment: apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$ sudo make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
apcoer@apcoer-Aspire-Series:~/Desktop/libgraph-1.0.2$ sudo make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.                                                                                                                              Still getting this error

Comment: `sudo apt-get install make`.